# is there a cleaner way to reset the starting drawing point in opengl - for android

Tags: android, opengl-es

so I am drawing a bunch of square plains to my GLView and wondering if there is a cleaner way to reset the glTransatef between each square..  my first square lets say is on -5 of the z axis and then the next square i want to draw at +5 on the axis.

```
     gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);     // move 5 units INTO the screen
     square.draw(gl);

     gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);     // move 10 units to compensate for last point
     square2.draw(gl);
```

another question i have is currently my two square classes have different matirx to so that they are viewable from the opposite side as the other.  Is there a way to just have one square class and change the way its facing when i draw it instead of having a completely different class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

glPushMatrix glPopMatrix

```
 glPushMatrix();
 gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);     // move 5 units INTO the screen
 square.draw(gl);
 glPopMatrix();

 glPushMatrix();
 gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, +5.0f);     // move 10 units to compensate for last point
 square2.draw(gl);
 glPopMatrix();
```

**EDIT**

*glPushMatrix* creates a copy of the currently active matrix (in the current matrix mode and stack) and pushes it to the top of the matrix stack. All matrix operations happen on the top of the matrix stack. *glPopMatrix* removes the matrix on the top of the stack, so that all further matrix operations (in the current matrix mode and stack) operate on the matrix that was saved with the corresponsing push.

Note that with OpenGL-ES 2 and OpenGL 3 and later there are no longer matrix manipulation functions, so this is all a bit obsolte these days.

#### Update for second sub-question

> another question i have is currently my two square classes have different matirx to so that they are viewable from the opposite side as the other. Is there a way to just have one square class and change the way its facing when i draw it instead of having a completely different class?

Just make that 2nd matrix a class member and set it as per the class constructor. Actually, I don't really understand your problem. A code example would help.

Comment: can you speak a bit as to what Push and Pop actually do? also do you have any advice for the second part of my question:
"another question i have is currently my two square classes have different matirx to so that they are viewable from the opposite side as the other. Is there a way to just have one square class and change the way its facing when i draw it instead of having a completely different class?"

Comment: Im drawing two squares.. square1 and square2.  They are currently separate classes, that draw a square but at different angles so that they are facing 0,0,0.  I'd like to just have one class called square and as i draw a new one, in a new x,y,z location, just tell it to face 0,0,0

Comment: note i will eventually be applying textures to every square and placing them dynamically via a JSON feed or something

Comment: @erik: I still don't see, what your actual problem is. Implement a class "square", subclass it from e.g. "drawobject" or so, and let it have some member variables that parametize the drawing. Give the class some methods to change the values of those variables, and set them also with the constructor. Then in the drawing code (a virtual method of "drawobject" you overwrite) use the values of those member variables to influence the drawing. Then you can have an arbitrary number of squares.

Comment: Well i would like to not have to have my app do calculations to figure out what the new matrix for a square is depending on the position of the cartesian graph.  I would like all squares to be 

{10,0,-10}
{10,0,10}
{-10,0,-10}
{-10,0,10}

when they are drawn.. i am asking essentially if there is a method to just after the square is draw and textureized to just make it rotate to face 0,0,0 no matter where it is on the cartesian graph..  

somthing like 

     sqaure.draw(gl);
     square.faceCenter(); //i made that up.. i am asking if there is a method that does that..

Comment: @erik: No there is not, because that's not how OpenGL works. OpenGL is a drawing API, not a scene graph. You tell it, what it got to draw, OpenGL draws and forgets about it. Also those calculations are not very diffucult, nor heavy. **The OpenGL matrix manipulation functions (glTranslate, glRotate, etc.) don't operate on objects**, and they don't "move" things. They just set a few matrix values, which all futher incoming vertices are put through.

Comment: So knowing that what i want the opengl to draw is a bunch of squares with pngs from the internet as their textures and their location being dynamic is their an easy way to make sure they always are drawn facing 0,0, 0? I have to write a class that will recieve an x, y, z coordinate and an image for each of an array of objects and be figure the matrix of each square so that it is always angled to face 0, 0,0

Comment: @erik: The vector (x,y,z)-(0,0,0) = (x,y,z) = ↑d. You need to define some "up" vector ↑u; (0,1,0) usually does the job. Orthogonalize ↑u and take the cross product of it with ↑d yielding v↑. Now ↑u, ↑v and ↑d form the base of a local coordinate system. write this as matrix [v, u, -d, d] and use this matrix as transformation for each quad. Note that for only 4 vertices per quad it's more efficient to do the calculation on CPU than uploading a full blown matrix to the GPU. You can however pass (x,y,z) as instancing attributes and do the calculation in a vertex shader. Google  "instanced drawing"

Comment: I don't know if its cause im currentlt out on my phone drinking a pint or something else entirely but i can not understand a word you just said.  In fact i see a bunch of special chatacters that are arrows pointing up where "i"s should be

Comment: @erik: Those are supposed to be arrows, designating the following as a vector. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonalization and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_Product – those are essential knowledge if you want to do 3D graphics!